# Sorting alphabetically .csv data in liquid using an unorderd list produces an empty list element

Tags: sorting, csv, liquid, alphabetical

I have managed to display the data from a .csv file in liquid for my jekyll website in alphabetical order but the code I'm using just adds an empty `<li>` tag in the beginning of the whole list. It seems to me that the "split" filter is responsible for the output's formatting so maybe there is something.

Here is my code in liquid:

```
---
layout: default
---
{% capture thelistings %}
  {% for listing in site.data.terminology %}
    {{ listing.term }}: {{ listing.definition }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}
{% assign allsortedlistings = thelistings | split:"    " | sort %}

<ul>
{% for allterms in allsortedlistings %}
<li>{{ allterms }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

here is the .csv data file:

```
term,definition
brother,new explanation for one
aunt,another explanation for two
uncle,"and last one for three, with the use of comma fin"
father,this is it
again,now it is here
utah,this is a state
borrow,something from someone
forbidden,fruit
```

and here is the output list:

- 
- again: now it is here
- aunt: another explanation for two
- borrow: something from someone
- brother: new explanation for one
- father: this is it
- forbidden: fruit
- uncle: and last one for three, with the use of comma fin
- utah: this is a state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lied in the way I outputted the data. When doing the first `{% capture %}` You have to format the data as you wish it to be outputted, in this case I wanted it to be a list item so it should look like this `<li>{{ listing.term }}: {{ listing.definition }}</li>`, thus wrapping it inside the `<li>` element and then passing it assigned as `{{ allterms }}` inside the `<ul>`. So the final code would look like:

```
---
layout: default
---
{% capture thelistings %}
  {% for listing in site.data.terminology %}
    <li>{{ listing.term }}: {{ listing.definition }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}
{% assign allsortedlistings = thelistings | split:"   " | sort %}

    <ul>
{% for allterms in allsortedlistings %}
        {{ allterms }}
{% endfor %}
    </ul>
```